# Compute the first six terms of the following sequences (start with n = 1):

Tags: sequences-and-series

Compute the first six terms of the following sequence (start with $n = 1$):

sequence $C = n + (n+1) + (n+2) + \cdots + (2n)$

I'm confused on what the "$\cdots$" mean. I thought a sequence was just plug in $n$ and solve but this appears to involve another step.

Comment: For reference, the $\cdots$ just means you should continue following the same pattern. In this case, follow it until you hit $2n$.

Comment: Thank you, Aleksander! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is all you have to do!

The formula for the $n$th term, $C_n$, is just the sum of all the integers from $n$ up to $2n$.

So

- $C_1=1+2=3$
- $C_2=2+3+4=9$
- $C_3=3+4+5+6=18$
- $C_4=4+5+6+7+8=30$

Now try it for $n=5$ and $n=6.$

Answer (score 2):

The sum can be written as:
$$S=\sum_{k=0}^n(k+n)=\frac{3}{2}n(n+1)$$
put $n$ inside the formula and you get $S$

Answer (score 1):

Besides the direct way suggested you can find a way to express $C_{n}$ in terms of $C_{n-1}$:
$$C_{n-1} = (n-1) + n + (n+1) +  \cdots + (2n-2)$$ 
$$C_{n} = n+ (n+1) + (n+2) +  \cdots + 2n$$ 
You can notice that $$C_{n}=C_{n-1}-(n-1)+(2n-1)+2n=C_{n-1}+3n\ .$$
It is easy then to compute the first terms:
$$C_1=1+2=3\qquad C_2=3+6=9\qquad C_3=9+9=18$$
$$ C_4=18+12=30\qquad C_5=30+15=45\qquad C_6=45+18=63$$

Answer (score 0):

$n = 1: \quad  1 + 2(1) = 1 + 2 = 3$

$n = 2: \quad 2 + (2+1) + 2(2) = 2 + 3 + 4 = 9$

$n = 3: \quad 3 + (3+1) + (3 + 2) + 2(3) = 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 18$

$n = 4:\quad 4 + (4+1) + (4 + 2) + (4 + 3) + 2(4) = 4 + 5+6+7+8 = 30$

$\quad \vdots$

Continue as above for $n = 5, n = 6$